# MYSQL 8.0 Bring all results, including zeroed ones

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

Business rule: Calculate the printing volume of a given department and his child departments, even if there is no printing.

MySQL Version 8.0 Schema SQL

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `departments` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `parent_department` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_department_department_idx` (`parent_department` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_department_department`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_department`)
    REFERENCES `departments` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prints` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `pages` INT NOT NULL,
  `copies` INT NOT NULL,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `department_id` INT NULL,
  `printer_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_print_department1_idx` (`department_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_print_department1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`)
    REFERENCES `departments` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

insert into departments (id,name,parent_department)
values
(1,'Department 1',null),
(2,'Department 2',null),
(3,'Department 3',1),
(4,'Department 4',null),
(5,'Department 5',1);

insert into prints (id,pages,copies,date,department_id,printer_id)
values
(1,3,1,'2019-06-30',2,1),
(2,8,2,'2019-06-30',3,2),
(3,10,2,'2020-12-02',2,6),
(4,3,1,'2020-12-02',1,4),
(5,9,2,'2020-12-02',1,1),
(6,5,3,'2020-12-05',2,5),
(7,5,7,'2020-12-05',1,4),
(8,3,2,'2020-12-05',1,1),
(9,1,1,'2020-12-25',2,3),
(10,4,1,'2020-12-25',1,2),
(11,9,2,'2020-12-25',1,1);
```

Query:

```sql
SET @initial_date = '2020-12-01';
SET @final_date = '2020-12-15';
SET @department_id = 1;

WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    d1.id, d1.name, d1.parent_department
  FROM
    departments d1
  WHERE d1.id=@department_id
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    d3.id, d3.name, d3.parent_department
  FROM
  CTE dCTE, departments d3
  WHERE d3.parent_department = dCTE.id
)

SELECT
  dCTE.id,
  dCTE.name AS department,
  d4.name AS parent_department,
  COALESCE(SUM(i.copies * i.pages), 0) AS total_print,
COUNT(DISTINCT i.printer_id) AS printer_count
FROM CTE dCTE
LEFT JOIN departments d4 ON d4.id = dCTE.parent_department
LEFT JOIN prints i ON i.department_id = dCTE.id
WHERE (i.date IS NULL OR i.date BETWEEN @initial_date AND @final_date)
GROUP BY dCTE.id, dCTE.name, d4.name
ORDER BY total_print DESC, department ASC
```

Actual Result:

```
id  department     parent_department   total_print  printer_count
1   Department 1          null              62            2
5   Department 5       Department 1         0             0
```

Expected Result:

```
id  department     parent_department   total_print  printer_count
1   Department 1          null              62            2
3   Department 3       Department 1         0             0   <--- this is the missing row
5   Department 5       Department 1         0             0
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7FLxFS2nfyUPJdXWPRjSpF/3

The problem: For some reason, one of the child departments is not being returned.

Any ideas?

Thx for the help

Comment: Because the print date `2019-06-30` isn't within the selected range, `2020-12-01` to `2020-12-15`.  (+1 for such a clear question with all of the needed info).

Comment: Hey. @SOS Thanks for the answer.

So, that's the point of the problem.

I need to bring all the child departments, even if there was no print.
If there was no print, just come with zero value.

But from your answer, shouldn't department 5 also come in the result or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, Department 5 should be included too.  Dept 3 is getting dropped due to WHERE clause. You have to move the filter into the LEFT JOIN.  Let me write it up ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately it's getting filtered out by the WHERE clause. The JOIN's detect the Department 3 record:

| name | id | pages | copies | date | department_id | printer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Department 3 | 2 | 8 | 2 | 2019-06-30 | 3 | 2 |

But then the WHERE clause checks that record's print date against the filters:

```
...
WHERE (i.date IS NULL OR i.date BETWEEN @initial_date AND @final_date)
```

Since the `date` value is NOT null, its then compared against the date range (`2020-12-01` through `2020-12-15`). Since `2019-06-30` is obviously outside that range, the record is dropped.

Instead, move the date filter into the LEFT JOIN statement:

```
...
SELECT
      dCTE.id,
      dCTE.name AS department,
      d4.name AS parent_department,
      COALESCE(SUM(i.copies * i.pages), 0) AS total_print,
      COUNT(DISTINCT i.printer_id) AS printer_count
FROM CTE dCTE
LEFT JOIN departments d4 ON d4.id = dCTE.parent_department
LEFT JOIN prints i ON i.department_id = dCTE.id
      AND i.date BETWEEN @initial_date AND @final_date
GROUP BY dCTE.id, dCTE.name, d4.name
ORDER BY total_print DESC, department ASC
```

Comment: I think thank you is too little for you.

You went way beyond the answer. You explained in detail where the error was and why it was occurring and how to fix it.

The stackoverflow community gains a lot from this kind of answer.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) Personally I think knowing the "why" is as important as the knowing the "fix".